# Spring Cloud Data Flow (version 2.11.0) is failing at launch with DB2 instance (DB2 v11.5)

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

After building the SCDF with custom Db2 driver, while trying to launch the server (spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT) is failing with:
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.common.flyway.DataFlowSchemaMigrationException: An exception occured during migration.  This may indicate that you have run Spring Batch Jobs or Spring Cloud Tasks prior to running Spring Cloud Data Flow first. Data Flow must create these tables.
at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.common.flyway.AbstractCallback.handle(AbstractCallback.java:76)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.callback.DefaultCallbackExecutor.handleEvent(DefaultCallbackExecutor.java:134)
... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE TABLE TASK_EXECUTION (
TASK_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
START_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
END_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
TASK_NAME  VARCHAR(100),
EXIT_CODE INTEGER,
EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2500),
ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2500),
LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP,
EXTERNAL_EXECUTION_ID VARCHAR(255),
PARENT_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT
)]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-601, SQLSTATE=42710, SQLERRMC=BFDBUSR.TASK_EXECUTION;TABLE, DRIVER=4.32.28

1. Should launch properly with the given Data source for Db2 instance under desired schema.
2. Environmental variables are not honored by SCDF (for DB2 in said context):

export spring_datasource_url=jdbc:db2://HOST:50000/MYDB

export spring_datasource_username=root

export spring_datasource_password=password

export spring_datasource_driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

export spring_datasource_initialization_mode=always

export spring_datasource_schema=MYSCHEMA

Tried with H2 db "jdbc:h2:mem:dataflow" and the same is getting connected and tables are created.(with above environmental variables but "export spring_datasource_schema=MYSCHEMA" is not recognized)

3. Few tables are duplicated (specific list mentioned below) but in runtime only main tables are populated not below ones:

- BOOT3_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
- BOOT3_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
- BOOT3_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
- BOOT3_BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
- BOOT3_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION
- BOOT3_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
- BOOT3_TASK_EXECUTION
- BOOT3_TASK_EXECUTION_PARAMS
- BOOT3_TASK_LOCK
- BOOT3_TASK_TASK_BATCH

Ref: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3177 (no resolution)

My problem statement: Standalone SFDC launch with DB2 failing with mentioned error (DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-601, SQLSTATE=42710, SQLERRMC=BFDBUSR.TASK_EXECUTION;TABLE, DRIVER=4.32.28), no tasks or batch is run individually.

My expectation: SCDF and Spring batch related tables should be created by SCDF itself honoring my schema (spring_datasource_schema=MYSCHEMA).